# How do I replace unicode character u00A0 with a space in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking to replace a bad character that a content editable div uses when a space is added at the end of the input.

Here is what I've tried

```
var text = $(this).text();
text.replace(/\u00A0/, " ");
```

But when I check the value of the last character like this

```
text.charCodeAt(text.length-1)
```

The value is still 160 instead of 32

Comment: Why not just cut the last character? Smth like this: `text.substr(0, -1)`

Comment: I need the last character since this text is a query parameter to a filter

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In javascript strings are immutable and replace return new string, try this:

```
var text = $(this).text();
text = text.replace(/\u00A0/, " ");
```

or in one line:

```
var text = $(this).text().replace(/\u00A0/, " ");
```

also if you want to replace all instances of the character, you need to add g flag to the regex `/\u00A0/g`.